# Build dataframe from matrix - specify column types

Tags: julia

Ok lets say I have a series of arrays:

```
data_one = ["dog","cat"]
data_two = [1,2]
data_three = ["1/1/2018","1/2/2018"]
```

I build them into a matrix

```
m = hcat(data_one,data_two,data_three)
```

and convert to a df

```
df = DataFrame(m)
showcols(df)
```

for output:

```
julia> showcols(df)
3×5 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ variable │ eltype │ nmissing │ first    │ last     │
├─────┼──────────┼────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ x1       │ Any    │ 0        │ dog      │ cat      │
│ 2   │ x2       │ Any    │ 0        │ 1        │ 2        │
│ 3   │ x3       │ Any    │ 0        │ 1/1/2018 │ 1/2/2018 │
```

When I build this data frame - how may I specify the types of each column??

```
col1 should be String 
col2 = Int 
col3 = String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it only indirectly through the following `DataFrame` constructor (of course you could pass `[String, Int, String]` as a variable here):

```
DataFrame([([String, Int, String][i]).(m[:,i]) for i in 1:size(m, 2)])
```

and if you want to use automatic detection of column type you can use:

```
DataFrame([[v for v in m[:,i]] for i in 1:size(m, 2)])
```